# VBA - fastest way of putting a string of csv into spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I was trying to put a string of csv I get from HTTP request into a excel spread sheet via VBA, i.e., by using

```
request = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
```

And pass the response to a string object. I was wondering if there's a better way than just doubling looping the string by splitting the string by new line and then splitting each line again by comma.

Comment: If you can save the CSV with a `.csv` extension, you should be able to open it in Excel using VBA. YMMV, as I've heard that the Microsoft CSV parsing is slightly broken.

Comment: @ZevSpitz thank you. Any idea about if that's faster/slower than parsing the string directly? I am thinking disk reading and writing is potentially slower, no?

Comment: Depends how big the CSV is, how much time you're going to spend debugging your own custom code, and how successful Excel is at parsing the CSV. I would try this method before anything else, and see if it's good enough. It's perhaps altogether 5-6 lines of code.

Comment: @ZevSpitz The code isn't particularly hard to write. I was just wondering if there's any existing excel function that does it (and potentially faster)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Dim csv As String
csv = "" 'get the CSV into this variable

Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2
Dim txt As Object
Set txt = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\output.csv", ForWriting, True)
txt.Write csv
txt.Close
Set txt = Nothing

Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application 'This may not be necessary if this code is running within an existing Excel application
xlApp.Workbooks.OpenText "c:\output.csv"
```

You may have to fiddle a bit with the parameters to `OpenText`.

---

References:

- [Workbooks.OpenText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837097.aspx) method